# Customizing the Weak limit

Tags: math-operators

Using the command `\displaystyle \lim_{\Lambda \uparrow \mathbb{Z}^2}` I can produce the limit that I desire. But I like to write the above limit as in the photo below. Could you help me? Thanked.

Ps. Correct me if I'm wrong about the Tags.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\DeclareMathOperator*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\limweak}{lim\,weak}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \limweak_{\Lambda \uparrow Z^2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `\substack`. (You will need to load the `amsmath` package):

```
$\substack{\mathrm{limweak}\\[0.1ex]\Lambda\uparrow Z}$
```

You can even define a command that takes as an argument the limit:

```
\newcommand{\limweak}[1]{\substack{\mathrm{limweak}\\[0.1ex]#1}}
```

P.S.: You can modify the height (`0.1ex`) to suit your needs.